# Adding two little endian byte array

Tags: java, arrays, byte, endianness

I have two byte array in little endian that I need to add. Obviosly this code doesn't work.

```
for (int i=0;i<bytes1.getB1().length;i++){
    bAdded[i]=(byte) (bytes1[i]+bytes2[i]);
}
```

How can I add these two little endian bytes array ?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean by "doesn't work"?

If you mean that it isn't performing carrying between bytes, here's how you could do it:

```
int carry = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < bytes1.getB1().length; i++) {
    int sum = bytes1[i] + bytes2[i] + carry;
    bAdded[i] = (byte) sum;
    carry = sum >> 8;
}

bAdded[bytes1.getB1().length] = carry;
```

Comment: I don't think that's right -- you never assign a value to `carry`.  It probably should be `carry = sum >> 8;`.

Comment: I mean doesn't work cause the little endian format, in my code the byte array is treated like no little endian.

Comment: @Hot Licks: You're right; fixed. Fischer: I don't know what you mean by "treated like no little endian".